# php - laravel with angularjs CRUD operation

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have implemented a simple CRUD with Angularjs in Laravel framework.
Followed all the steps, I am getting the value from db also.
But I am not able to call the view.
Please help??

when I call the view page JSON value get printed

```
{
 "current_page":1,
 "data":[],
 "from":null,
 "last_page":0,
 "next_page_url":null,
 "path":"http:\/\/localhost\/laravel\/public\/products",
 "per_page":5,
 "prev_page_url":null,
 "to":null,
 "total":0
}
```

[in Mozilla I get the page and in Chrome data comes printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWRvY.png)

Comment: Ler me try to understand your problem! You are implementing CRUD with angularjs and Laravel, normally this is done by using json documents via ajax to perform all CRUD operations! If u are doing this way! Can you share your view method inside your controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you return paginate in your controller

you should use `return view('bladefilename');`

for example :

```
public function index()
{
    $products = Product::paginate(5);
    return view('bladename',compact('products'));
}
```

**bladename** is the `bladename.blade.php` file in `resources/views` path

[Creating view document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#creating-views)